# Why does this code get executed twice? If recomposition... what triggers the recomposition?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I am Learning Android Compose, And I was looking/playing with this code from developers.android, in github.
The projects is a simple app to demonstrate adaptive screen. [Sports App](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-sports/tree/main)

Everything works fine, but am a but confused.

I logged an item/line to Logcat. And I see that it gets executed twice? Recomposition? What is causing it?[image: Screenshot of AS code]

Comment: Also log the hash code of the `selectedSport` to see if it is recomposed for same item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
Log.i("info", "xxx")

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
) {

    Box {
        Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.xx))
        Text()
    }

    Text(
        text = stringResource(R.string.app_name),
    )
}
```

The `stringResource` and `painterResource` can cause recomposition.
In compose when something triggers a recomposition, it happens in the nearest scope.
However the `Box` and the `Column` are **inline** function, and it means that both don't have an own recompose scopes.

In your code when the `Image` and the `Text` are recomposed all the composable is recomposed.

If you change your `Column` into a custom `Composable` it won't be recomposed.

Something like:

```
@Composable
private fun MyColumn() {
    //same code above
}
```

and then:

```
Log.i("info", "xxx")
MyColumn()
```

Comment: so, how can we handle it to not recompose on it (stringResource and painterResource)

Comment: @ShubhamMogarkar For example wrapping the Column in a Composable. Check the updated answer.